# Calculate how many sequences AB, with A;B ∈ P(S) exist such that A ∩ B = ∅.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{1,2, \cdots ,n\}$, and  $\mathcal{P}(S)$ be the power set of $2^n$ subsets of $S$.

$$\textrm{Calculate how many sequences AB with A,B} \in{\mathcal{P}(S)} \textrm{exists such that } A\cap{B}=\emptyset$$  if  $ A=(1,2) , B=3 $ then $(1,2)(3)\neq{}(3)(1,2)$

I tried with $n=2$ and $n=3$ and I got $9$ possibilities for $n=2$ and $27$ for $n=3$ but I don't see how to calculate it

Comment: Are you asking here to find the cardinality of $\{\langle A,B\rangle\mid A,B\in\wp(S)\wedge A\cap B=\varnothing\}$? It is $3^n$. For each $k\in S$ there are $3$ possibilities: $k\in A$,$k\in B$ and $k\notin A\cup B$.

Comment: Yes , I counted wrong for n=3 .How do you find that it´s equal to $3^n$?

Comment: Do you see that there is a one-to-one relation between functions $S\to\{1,2,3\}$ and pairs $\langle A,B\rangle$ with $A,B\subseteq S$ and $A\cap B=\varnothing$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal F$ denote the collection of functions $S\to\{0,1,2\}$. It is evident that $|\mathcal F|=3^n$

Let $\mathcal G:=\{\langle A,B\rangle\mid A,B\subseteq S\wedge A\cap B=\varnothing\}$.

Prescribe $f:\mathcal F\to\mathcal G$ by $f\mapsto\langle f^{-1}(\{1\}),f^{-1}(\{2\})\rangle$.

Prescribe $g:\mathcal G\to\mathcal F$ by $\langle A,B\rangle\mapsto 1_A+2.1_B$.

Then $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other and we conclude that $|\mathcal G|=|\mathcal F|=3^n$.